# Jabber XMPP chat client for iOS with push notifications

Tags: ios, chat

[Chat Secure](https://chatsecure.org/) is working on iOS with Jabber but it doesn't stay active in the background [(just for 10 minutes)](https://chatsecure.org/faq/) so it is not really an alternative to the internal iMessage Chat.

Which app is able to save Jabber messages offline and send them as push notifications as soon as you are online again?

I use iOS 7 on an iPad Air

Comment: which ios? which device ?

Answer (score -2):

Beejive Pro with Push is the solution !

Comment: Are you sure it works? 9,99 seems a  bit like fraud. And I cannot see any hint to OTR on the webpage

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.